# Populating a GridView and a DetailsView when a webform is first loaded

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms, detailsview

On a form that has both a summary GridView and a DetailsView we would like to have the DetailsView populate with data when the page is initially displayed without the user needing to click on the "Select Button" in the GridView.

If this can be done, can you show the needed coding?

Comment: Anything that you tried so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804830/set-detailsview-as-selected-row-of-gridview duplicate????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following...

When page get's loaded in page_load() check for page is postback == false;

In that get the first row's primary key field value.

```
E.g FirstRowValue = YourGried.DataSource.Table[0].Row[0][PrimaryKey];
```

then use that value to bind detail view.

```
E.g YourDetailView.DataSource =  GetDetailById(FirstRowValue);
YourDetailView.Databind();
```

This is simple logic and it would work.

Code it and if not work paste it... I am not putting code intentionally ;)